# Unable to build the java project in netbeans 12

Tags: java, netbeans, build, netbeans-platform

I am currently using Netbeans 12 with OpenJDK 11 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

My application ran successfully whenever I pressed F6 in Netbeans to check it.
Now when my code is completed, I pressed the build button but this error occured:

```
    ant -f "/home/nbs/NetBeansProjects/JO Planner" -Dnb.internal.action.name=run run
init:
Deleting: /home/nbs/NetBeansProjects/JO Planner/build/built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: /home/nbs/NetBeansProjects/JO Planner/build/built-jar.properties
Compiling 4 source files to /home/nbs/NetBeansProjects/JO Planner/build/classes
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

And after that I am not able to run the project using F6, the same error is shown please help me

Comment: I didn't found the suitable but answer but an advice saying that I should switch to Maven rather than Ant and the Maven doesn't have any issues to build the project

Answer (score 0):

The space in the project directory might be causing the issue. Try changing it to `/home/nbs/NetBeansProjects/JO_Planner` or `/home/nbs/NetBeansProjects/JOPlanner` or anything without a space in it.

Comment: I tried this but still the problem persisted.... and there is a wrench symbol over the file. Does it has to do anything with it? I have all classes made in source package ....